# Is There A Way I Can Unban Using My Discord.py Rewrite Bot

Tags: python, bots, discord, discord.py

How do i make an unban command in **Discord.py Rewrite** i wanted to clear my question because there is no bot.unban command (maybe it is) and the player is not in the list so i can mention the user

**Edit:**

````
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\BKhushi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 227, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\BKhushi\Desktop\gg\Discordgang.py", line 125, in on_command_error
    raise error
  File "C:\Users\BKhushi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 814, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\BKhushi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 675, in invoke
    await self.prepare(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\BKhushi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 640, in prepare
    await self._parse_arguments(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\BKhushi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 561, in _parse_arguments
    transformed = await self.transform(ctx, param)
  File "C:\Users\BKhushi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 427, in transform
    return await self.do_conversion(ctx, converter, argument, param)
  File "C:\Users\BKhushi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 382, in do_conversion
    return await self._actual_conversion(ctx, converter, argument, param)
  File "C:\Users\BKhushi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 328, in _actual_conversion
    ret = await instance.convert(ctx, argument)
  File "C:\Users\BKhushi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\converter.py", line 158, in convert
    raise BadArgument('User "{}" not found'.format(argument))
discord.ext.commands.errors.BadArgument: User "@<552510634303029298>" not found```
````

Comment: Please refrain from vandalizing your question. That way it loses its use for future readers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have a `Member` object representing a banned `Member`, you can use [`Member.unban`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Member.unban).  Most of the time, however, you'll instead have to get a `User` object representing that user and use [`Guild.unban`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Guild.unban):

```
from discord import User
from discord.ext.commands import Bot, guild_only

bot = Bot("!")

@bot.command(name='unban')
@guild_only()  # Might not need ()
async def _unban(ctx, id: int):
    user = await bot.fetch_user(id)
    await ctx.guild.unban(user)


bot.run("TOKEN")
```

Comment: It gives me that member not found

Comment: @bosgamer Could you edit the full error message into your question?

Comment: I Tried even that but same problem

Comment: @bosgamer I modified it to use `fetch_user`, which I know for a fact does not require you to be able to "see" that user to get their information.  Could you try again using that code?

Comment: thanks, but is there a way i can unban through mention not id?

Comment: The command you editted don't work it says "bot object has no attribute 'fetch_user' "

Comment: @bosgamer Make sure your discord.py installation is up to date.  There should be a [`fetch_user`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.fetch_user) coroutine

Comment: Oh ok il check, but whats the latest version?

Comment: Version 1.0.1   is what pip should give you when you do `pip3 install -U discord.py`, which should be sufficient.

Comment: if i write `pip3 install discord.py` is that okay?

Comment: Also that commands work on latest discord.py rewrite but is there a way i can mention to unban not use the id?

Comment: The `-U` is for "upgrade".  It should ensure you get the latest version. As to using mention, I'm not sure.  The default `UserConverter` uses `get_user` on the id it extracts, which seems to be failing because that user isn't stored in the internal cache, because the bot doesn't share any guilds with them.  You could probably write one that uses `fetch_user` instead, which gets the user details from the discord API.

Answer (score 3):

I would consider the below command. My apologies that it does not send a message after said action, to get more on how to write in Discord.Py Rewrite I recommend you watch 
[here](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCR-zOCvDCayyYy1flR5qaAg)!

```
  async def pardon(ctx, *, member):
      banned_users = await ctx.guild.bans()
      member_name, member_discriminator = member.split('#')

      for ban_entry in banned_users:
          user = ban_entry.banned_users

          if (user.name, user.discriminator) == (member_name, member_discriminator):
              await ctx.guild.unban(user)
```

Comment: Whoops I messed up!

Comment: it writes ban_entry has no attribute banned_users

Answer (score 0):

Try using this
It worked for me. instead of member:discord.Member do member:discord.User as the user is for a user in discord and member is a member in a discord server

```
@client.command()
@commands.has_role(1234567890) # Role ID
@commands.cooldown(1,15, commands.BucketType.user)
async def unban(ctx, member:discord.User, *, reason=None):
    if reason == None:
        reason = f"No Reason Provided"
    await ctx.guild.unban(member, reason=reason)
    await ctx.send(f"{member.mention} has been **unbanned**", delete_after=15)
    embed = discord.Embed(title="Unban Log", description=f"{member.mention} has been **unbanned** by {ctx.author.mention}\n\nReason: `{reason}`\n\nUnbanned from: `{ctx.guild.name}`", color=0x1355ed)
    embed.add_field(name="User", value=f"{member}", inline=True)
    embed.add_field(name="UserID", value=f"{member.id}", inline=True)
    embed.add_field(name="Moderator", value=f"{ctx.author}", inline=True)
    embed.set_footer(text=f"Unban log - Banned user: {member.name}")
    embed.set_thumbnail(url=member.avatar_url)
    embed.timestamp = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
    logchannel = client.get_channel(988416086217203732)
    await logchannel.send(embed=embed)
    await ctx.message.delete()
    print(f"Sucsessfully unbanned {member.name}")
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Code is a lot more helpful when it is accompanied by an explanation. Stack Overflow is about learning, not providing snippets to blindly copy and paste. Please [edit] your answer and explain how it answers the specific question being asked. See [answer].